# Magento Sale Reports on Frontend

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am working on a B2B site built in Magento which is a little different than normal Magento projects.

They want to pull some of the backend information to the front end.

All company personal who view the site, log in prior to viewing the frontend site thus I can set a role / handle permissions.

Would it be possible to print(on the storefront), all the information is in the backend just needs to be pulled out I imagine:

- The number of qty of that product that has been sold
- A page listing all the orders from that product e.g. Product 1 has a link on the product view titled "view all orders" and this shows all the orders of that product showing:
- Qty
- Email of user
- Customer group

Has anyone done similar like this or pass on advice/concerns.

Thanks

--

Cameron

Comment: speaking about roles and permissions aren't you mixing front-end and back-end users?

Comment: Frontend customer can see report data that is correct.

Comment: but as far as I understand Magento ACL is only applicable to admin users.

Comment: Could we not pull that information out though on the frontend? Alternatively pulling just the stock report out on the frontend

Comment: I think in their it is possible but on practice it will take too much time and effort.

Comment: Any words or snippets of code that may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way I have looked at achieving this was using the Magento API

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $product_id = $model->load($productid);  

        $filters = array(
            'state'   => array('eq' => 'complete')
        );


        $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order_api_v2')->items($filters);
```

The problem lies however that Magento is not reading the filter.

Help much appreciated